# How to get an instance of Jasper PdfExporterConfiguration?

Tags: groovy, jasper-reports

We're using JasperReports plugin for Grails to generate PDF server-side, using `JasperService` and `JasperReportDef`. We recently updated the plugin and JasperReports and discovered that `JRPdfExporterParameter` is now deprecated in favour of `PdfExporterConfiguration`

We had code like this:

```
def reportDef = new JasperReportDef([
    name        : templateName,
    fileFormat  : JasperExportFormat.PDF_FORMAT,
    reportData  : exportRows,
    parameters  : [
        (JRPdfExporterParameter.METADATA_AUTHOR) : 'Company Name'
    ],
])
```

Deprecation JavaDoc suggests using `PdfExporterConfiguration.getMetadataAuthor()` instead. But it's an instance method - and `PdfExporterConfiguration` is just an interface! - while `JRPdfExporterParameter.METADATA_AUTHOR` is a static constant.

Where can I get an instance of `PdfExporterConfiguration` to use?

Answer (score 1):

I use this (note pure java never worked with Grails):

```
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
```

it `implements` the `PdfExporterConfiguration` and you can set the `METADATA`.

```
configuration.setMetadataAuthor("Petter");
```

Don't know how any other classes that implements PdfExporterConfiguration, let me know if you find some.

Comment: And how should this configuration be applied to `JasperReportDef` instance?

Comment: Sadly I have never worked with Grails, in pure java it is added to the  'exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);' where the exporter is the JRPdfExporter, checking some of the source code of JasperReportDef seems that you can only set parameters so if the parameter does not work, i guess you need to wait for them to implement it correctly